# Launching/connecting available virtual machine from a win10 home edition

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

Hi there I wl like to understand: How to do starting a virtual machine and launch it from my client (windows 10 Home Edition based Laptop) using the DNS and credentials provided ? I got the DNS and user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the VM created and turned off, then you should go to the Azure portal and turn it on, then use Remote Desktop Protocol from your local machine to connect to that virtual machine.